# How to obtain full host name?

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, hostname

when I write following code in cmd:

```
ping localhost
```

I see following result:

```
Pinging hostname.A.B.com [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
```

When I write

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName();
```

it returns only `hostname`

How can I achieve to return `hostname.A.B.com` from java code ?

### P.S.

It is not duplicate.  I use code from top answer but I don't achieve desired result.

Comment: What result do you achieve?

Comment: expected result: **hostname.A.B.com** from **java code**

Comment: actual result: **hostname** from **java code**

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you grab the *localhost* address `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` so if you haven't put your fully qualified name for your host, you only get the hostname. In linux (and probably OS X and other UNIX system), you need to add your qualified hostname to `/etc/hosts` to your localhost entry for this to work.